# A/D Converter with Hall Effect Sensor

Tags: circuit-analysis, adc, hall-effect

I am trying to produce a circuit that uses the output of a hall effect sensor and feeds it into a A/D converter. I have a couple of questions about how this process will take place. Below is a circuit of what I am trying to accomplish. Essentially, an IC AND gate allows for 5V to be passed to the Hall Effect Sensor. This voltage is then passed through the sensor with its adjusted voltage as the output. This analog value is then passed to the A/D converter which then passes it along to an FPGA.

[image]

1. For starters, the Hall Effect Sensor has an operating voltage range of 3V to 24V, I plan to feed it 5V. My concern is how this would effect the output. Does my output voltage also get bound to this minimum voltage, i.e. is my output range 3V to 5V? Ideally I would want a range of 0V to 5V to be fed into the A/D converter.
2. Originally the GND of U2 were also tied to -IN, but I figured if there was an offset as a result of the input at U3, setting a virtual ground of 3V would give me a full range of 0V to 2V. This could be completely off base. Alternatively, I was thinking of keeping the range from 3V to 5V and just having the controller handle the shift.
3. I'm sure there are some other things I missed when making this circuit

Comment: That sensor looks to have an open-drain on-off output.  Is there a reason you are feeding it into an A/D?

Comment: The plan is have an analog output from the hall sensor that can be a range of values. The application is to have an FPGA control power based upon the output of the hall sensor. So, if the Hall Sensor is at its max value, the FPGA reads out max power, and if its at its min, then the FPGA passes it as off.

Comment: Then you will need a different type of sensor.  The one you have now is designed to only switch between two discrete states.  Search for "hall effect analog" sensors.

Comment: That was definitely the right direction, do you have any idea about the operating parameters for these sensors? I'm looking at a couple from TI that operate between 2.5V and 5V and am not sure if I should implement a virtual ground like I did in my circuit.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear as to the initial rationale for the virtual ground, but I doubt it's necessary if you select a sensor with a full range output.  Depending on your sensor, you may also need to put in an op-amp buffer stage to feed your A/D and could do any massaging of the output there.

Comment: It was a poor attempt to get the signal to be rated against 0V. And yeah, it looks like an opamp will be the best bet. I'm seeing the Quiescent Voltage Output on the spec sheet and assume it acts as an offset.

Comment: There are also Hall sensors with digital outputs. I2C seems most popular, but I think Melexis offers a selection with SPI output. Most are 3-axis, but nobody will stop you from ignoring the data from two of the three directions. Many (but not all!) are tiny surface mount chips that require skill and good equipment to hand solder. But, you can get the venerable LIS3MDL on a breakout board from a variety of sources.

Comment: Was just looking into those sensors with digital outputs, specifically the LIS3MDL. I just am looking for a 1-axis detector that can output a digital signal. I think I'll have to go with a I2C transfer as the signal is going to be travelling through a long cable. If the IC sends out data in 8 bit intervals, do I need to compensate that in the FPGA at all, and I read that I2C need a bit slower of a clock, so is 100MHz a bit too short an interval for this connection?